# CSS Background Color not Scaling ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a master page with some CSS for a background and am also using a another div to give a content box around what I wish to place on the page.  However when I scale the content div to say 1000px the background div doesn't seem to see that I've expanded the content div beyond what it's current height is.  Anyone have any ideas on this?  I was thinking it had to do with the master page content controls but am not sure.

Some of what I have here has been me playing with it.  For example the content box I hardcoded to a height of 100% but it won't have that as I want the content box to expand based on its content.  But the hardcoded height allowed me to show the fact of how the background is not sizing with the content.

Here is the code:
CSS:

```
body
{
border: 0px none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;   
}

.Button
{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: large;
font-weight: bold;
color:White;
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
border-color: Black;
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 25px; 
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
clear: both;
background: rgb(208,228,247); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%, rgba(115,177,231,1) 

24%, rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%, rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%, rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(208,228,247,1)), color-stop(24%,rgba(115,177,231,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(10,119,213,1)), color-stop(79%,rgba(83,159,225,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(135,188,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 79%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d0e4f7', endColorstr='#87bcea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

}

.Button:hover
{
    background: rgb(247,208,228); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(135,188,234,1) 0%, rgba(208,228,247,1) 24%, rgba(115,177,231,1) 50%, rgba(10,119,213,1) 79%, rgba(83,159,225,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(135,188,234,1)), color-stop(24%,rgba(208,228,247,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(115,177,231,1)), color-stop(79%,rgba(10,119,213,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(83,159,225,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(135,188,234,1) 0%,rgba(208,228,247,1) 24%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 50%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 79%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(135,188,234,1) 0%,rgba(208,228,247,1) 24%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 50%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 79%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(135,188,234,1) 0%,rgba(208,228,247,1) 24%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 50%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 79%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(135,188,234,1) 0%,rgba(208,228,247,1) 24%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 50%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 79%,rgba(83,159,225,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87bcea', endColorstr='#d0e4f7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.Button:active
{
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}


/*Login Page */
#LoginBox
{

    position: absolute;
    min-height: 1px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
    background: #88bfe8; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%, #70b0e0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#88bfe8), color-stop(100%,#70b0e0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#88bfe8', endColorstr='#70b0e0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.LoginControls
{
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    margin:-50px 0 0 -100px;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
}

.WelcomeLabel
{
    top:15%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-25px 0 0 -50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

/*Data Entry Page */
#DataEntryContent
{

    position: absolute;
    min-height: 1px;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #88bfe8; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%, #70b0e0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#88bfe8), color-stop(100%,#70b0e0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#88bfe8', endColorstr='#70b0e0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}


/*General */
.ContentBackground
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 1px; 
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(59,103,158); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%, rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(59,103,158,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(43,136,217,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.Line
{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    min-height:1px;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
    height:1px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}


.Labels
{

    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.TextBoxes
{
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ContentBox
{

    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #88bfe8; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%, #70b0e0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#88bfe8), color-stop(100%,#70b0e0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #88bfe8 0%,#70b0e0 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#88bfe8', endColorstr='#70b0e0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

#BannerImage
{
    width: 297px;
    height: 59px;    
}


ul, li{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}  

.menu_head{border:1px solid #998675;}  
.menu_body {width:184px;border-right:1px solid #998675;border-bottom:1px solid #998675;border-left:1px solid #998675;}  
.menu_body {display:none; width:184px;border-right:1px solid #998675;border-bottom:1px solid #998675;border-left:1px solid #998675;}  
.menu_body li{background:#493e3b;}
.menu_body li a{color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; padding:10px; display:block;}
.menu_body li.alt{background:#362f2d;}  
.menu_body li a:hover{padding:15px 10px; font-weight:bold;}
```

ASP Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MyProject.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>MyProject Web</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="~/Styles/superfish.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/hoverIntent.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/SiteMaster.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="Banner">
                <img id="BannerImage" alt="Logo" src="/images/Logo.gif" />
                <ul class="sf-menu">  
                  <!--List for Javascript Menu -->
                </ul>                      
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ContentBackground">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">Test</div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Entry.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.Entry.Entry" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <div class="ContentBox">
 Test
 </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Could you provide the just the HTML and CSS, instead of the ASP.net code?  There's an awful lot to dig through here.  You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains **just enough** code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, . Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue you are running into is mainly caused by the child element (`ContentBox`) and parent element (`ContentBackground`) in your stylesheet both having *absolute* positioning.

If you edit your css slightly, it should correct your problem.

Remove `height: 100%;` and `position: absolute;` from `.ContentBackground`

and

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.ContentBox`

Here is an article that may help you learn more about positioning: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/